# unable to select "next" when selector wrapped in tags

Tags: jquery, selector

I can't find a way to select elements when the selector is wrapped in an html tag.

The jQuery works fine but as soon as the selector is wrapped in an html tag (any tag) the onclick function doesn't trigger an event or function.

Just some sample code (and codepen below):

HTML:

```
OK: The <a class="collapse one">first link</a> and a <button class="collapse two">button</button> both open one and two, and <button class="collapse three">another button</button> opens just the first.
<p class="collapsible one">Collapse one via link</p>
<p class="collapsible two">Collapse two via button</p>
<hr />
NOT OK: The same but the line is now wrapped in &lt;em> tags, (but same for &lt;p> tags, &lt;div> tags etc.),<br />
<em>The <a class="collapse one">first link</a> and a <button class="collapse two">button</button> both open one and two, and <button class="collapse three">another button</button> opens just the first.</em>
<p class="collapsible one">Collapse one via link</p>
<p class="collapsible two">Collapse two via button</p>
```

jQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.collapse.one, .collapse.two').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.collapsible.one, .collapsible.two').slideToggle();
    }).nextAll('.collapsible.one, .collapsible.two').hide();

    $('.three').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }).next().hide();
});
```

See this codepen with sample code: https://codepen.io/cnxpat/pen/MWgBYNz

Thanks in advance for any assistance, I have been struggling with this for quite a few days.

Comment: When you wrap the links/buttons in an element, the collapsible elements are no longer siblings of the links/buttons. That's why `.next()` no longer works. In these cases you can try jumping up a level in the node tree by using `.parent()`. Not sure if this cover all your needs, but hopefully it can point you in the right direction: `$(this).parent().next().slideToggle();`.

Comment: Hi @agrm, awesome, that covers my needs! Not sure how I can mark this as the correct answer, since it is a comment.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad you got this solved. Sorry for my late response but I have written a proper answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, `.next()` works because the collapsible elements are siblings of your links/buttons. In your second example where the links/buttons are wrapped in an `<em>`, they are no longer siblings of the collapsible elements. That's why .next() no longer works.

In these cases you will have to jump up a level in the node tree by using .parent(). From there you can select the collapsible elements using `.next()`. In your case this should work:

```
$(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
```